# Store a result to a variable in prolog?

Tags: prolog

```
parent(max,alex).

?- parent(max,alex).
"true."
?- parent(max,jack).
"false."

?- X = parent(max,jack), write(X). // Why X != false?
"X = parent(max, jack)."
```

How to store to X answer from query "parent(max,jack)"(true or false)?

Comment: Use `parent(max, X).` `X` was false in your case because prolog predicates are not functions. With `X = parent(max,jack)`, you unified `X` with `parent(max,jack)` which yields `X = parent(max,jack)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're trying to do is find out if `parent(max, jack)` is going to succeed. Usually in Prolog you would do something like this:

```
foo :-
  parent(max, jack),
  % if you make it here, the predicate is true
  ...
foo :-
  % since you're here, the predicate is false
```

However, this may be obscured by whatever else you're doing. If you want to be more explicit about it, you can use the conditional construct:

```
foo :-
  (parent(max, jack) 
     -> % true case
      ; % else case)
```

If you want X to be true if this is true, you can do this:

```
foo :-
  (parent(max, jack) -> X = true ; X = false),
  ...
```

Comment: I totally glossed over the desire for `X` to have true or false. Good catch, Daniel (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Prolog doesn't have *functions*. It has *predicates*. They do not do the same thing.

So `X = parent(max,jack).` isn't a function call to `parent` that returns the result of `parent(max,jack)` into `X`.

`parent(max,jack)` is a predicate that inquires whether the relation `parent(max, jack)` is true. It is either true or false, and prolog will tell you whether it is true or false.

When you enter the above expression, `X = parent(max,jack)`, you are using the `=/2` predicate in prolog. That's the unification operator. That means "what's on the left is unified with what's on the right of the =". If there are variables on either side, prolog will attempt to instantiate the variables to make the expression TRUE. In this case, the statement is TRUE if prolog instantiates `X` with the expression `parent(max,jack)`. Thus, you get the result:

```
X = parent(max,jack).
```

If you want to query the `parent` relationship between `max` and an unknown, `X`, do this:

```
parent(max, X).
```

Then prolog will seek values of `X` to make the expression true, and you will get:

```
X = alex.
```

Comment: A little curious as to why the query returned alex rather than jack?

Comment: @afryingpan the only fact in the OP's asserted data is `parent(max, alex).` So, of course, the query `parent(max, X).` is going to result in, `X = alex`.

Comment: woops, didn't see his data, of course it's not jack as that'd be false. thanks